# Is Gmail Lab API open?

Tags: api, gmail, thunderbird-addon

I am thinking about writing a plugin for email application. It can be put on Gmail Labs. It can be thunderbird plugin or even chrome/firefox plugin. But to get the most exposure I should put it on Gmail Labs if possible. Actually, I don't know if it's possible at all. BTW, I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819528/gmail-plugin-api-development). Let me know what you think.

Comment: Gmail Labs is a place for Google to publish their own enhancements to Gmail for people to try out. It's not a place where anybody can submit applications or plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Gmail Labs is not open to external contributions. However, Gmail users can add external gadgets to Gmail.