# Will a function be added to Gmail App Script API to get the type of star assigned to a message?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Gmail settings allows to set a star of a different type among [several](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) ("yellow-star", "red-star", "green-check", ...).
The number of star types that can be used can be set in Gmail [settings menu](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=5904).

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)'s [Gmail services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_gmail) includes a [GmailMessage::isStarred](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailmessage#isStarred) that just returns a Boolean. It does not provide the type of star that is set.

Will this function be modified, or an other be added, to return which type of star is set to a message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that wishing for that to happen. The best place is fill an "Enhancement request" on Apps Script [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Anyway, since we're on this subject, you can get all messages of a specific star by issue the [appropriate search](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) on gmail.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to use [GmailApp::search()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#search) method to find stars of a given type until an other method is available. I also followed your advice and filled an [Enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1334) !

Comment: So, I tried to use GmailApp.Search('has:green-check'), unfortunately it does not work. I filed an [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1335) too.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the report, I starred it too.

Comment: The [report](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1191) I filed on the "goggle apps script issues" forum has finally had its status set to "WontFix", so I guess there is no hope to get support from Google on this issue.

Comment: Shame on Google. Has:red-bang works only in Browser, not in its Android Gmail app, not in its app scripts. And finally after so many votes, their answer is: won't fix. Shame on them.

Answer (score 5):

```
GmailApp.search('label:^ss_sg')
```

seems to work for getting green stars only.
The various codes are in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157723/unable-to-search-for-specific-coloured-star-superstars-using-advanced-search-i)