# Unable to search for specific coloured star (superstars) using Advanced Search in Gmail API.

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

This is what we used.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

In order to GET emails with a red star, this is what we requested.

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=has%3Ared-star&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The result was 0.
Other criteria such as is:starred, has:attachment worked just as expected, are we doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't see why q="has:green-check" would not work in the API if the same query works in web UI. If you get no results, be sure to make sure you're properly (URL) escaping the q parameter value (depending on language this may or may not be handled for your automatically).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the names of the flags in the Gmail API. You have to use the following codes:

```
has:yellow-star <=> l:^ss_sy
has:blue-star <=> l:^ss_sb 
has:red-star <=> l:^ss_sr 
has:orange-star <=> l:^ss_so
has:green-star <=> l:^ss_sg
has:purple-star <=> l:^ss_sp
has:red-bang <=> l:^ss_cr
has:yellow-bang <=> l:^ss_cy
has:blue-info <=> l:^ss_cb
has:orange-guillemet <=> l:^ss_co
has:green-check <=> l:^ss_cg
has:purple-question <=> l:^ss_cp
```

Source: http://googlesystem.blogspot.se/2008/07/gmail-superstars.html

Comment: @yoshi Great! :) Consider accepting the answer, so people with similar questions can find it.

Comment: Still cannot understand the logic. If "is:unread" works, and in general, you can specify query parameters similar to how you search in GMail search box, why does "has:XXX" does not work?

Comment: @ND003 I don't get it either :) Just something I picked up a while ago. Pretty annoying.