# Query search in Gmail API doesn't work as web version

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm trying to extract messages (Gmail API) with a certain color of the star.
For example, blue star.

```
def listMessagesMatchingQuery(service, user_id='me', query=''):
    try:
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,
                                                   q=query).execute()
        print(response)
        messages = []
        if 'messages' in response:
            messages.extend(response['messages'])

        while 'nextPageToken' in response:
            page_token = response['nextPageToken']
            response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query,
                                                   pageToken=page_token).execute()
            messages.extend(response['messages'])
        return messages

    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


print(listMessagesMatchingQuery(GMAIL, query="has:blue-star"))
```

And it doesn't work like a web version, it returns 0 emails. Another queries work well (tried "from:...", "has:attachment", "has:drive", "before:...", "after:..." etc). Can't find a solution, I need to sort emails by color of the stars.

Comment: Querying for the super stars in the Gmail API is quite tricky. You probably need to change it to e.g. `l:^ss_cb` for the blue star, like [**explained here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157723/unable-to-search-for-specific-coloured-star-superstars-using-advanced-search-i/31158059#31158059).

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped @Tholle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying for the super stars in the Gmail API is quite tricky. You probably need to change it to e.g. `l:^ss_sb` for the blue star, like [**explained in this blogpost**](https://googlesystem.blogspot.se/2008/07/gmail-superstars.html#gsc.tab=0).

```
has:yellow-star <=> l:^ss_sy
has:blue-star <=> l:^ss_sb 
has:red-star <=> l:^ss_sr 
has:orange-star <=> l:^ss_so
has:green-star <=> l:^ss_sg
has:purple-star <=> l:^ss_sp
has:red-bang <=> l:^ss_cr
has:yellow-bang <=> l:^ss_cy
has:blue-info <=> l:^ss_cb
has:orange-guillemet <=> l:^ss_co
has:green-check <=> l:^ss_cg
has:purple-question <=> l:^ss_cp
```